# How to add Hyperlink on treeWidget Stringelements from .ui file with PyQt5

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

The app uses a treeview widget with an hierarchy.
I don't know how to add links on to the lowest tree level (Doubleclick)
Does anyone know what I did wrong? Or how to implement the hyperlink on the string elements?
I have both of the files ready and the codes can be tested on your behalf as well.

the .ui file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>530</x>
      <y>10</y>
      <width>241</width>
      <height>61</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>36</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>TextLabel</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QTreeWidget" name="treeWidget">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>10</y>
      <width>361</width>
      <height>401</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <column>
     <property name="text">
      <string>DWH Toolkit</string>
     </property>
    </column>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>XY</string>
     </property>
     <item>
      <property name="text">
       <string>XY</string>
      </property>
     </item>
    </item>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>XY</string>
     </property>
     <item>
      <property name="text">
       <string>XY</string>
      </property>
     </item>
    </item>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>XY</string>
     </property>
     <item>
      <property name="text">
       <string>XY</string>
      </property>
     </item>
     <item>
      <property name="text">
       <string>XY</string>
      </property>
     </item>
    </item>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>XY</string>
     </property>
     <item>
      <property name="text">
       <string>XY</string>
      </property>
     </item>
     <item>
      <property name="text">
       <string>XY</string>
      </property>
     </item>
    </item>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>XY</string>
     </property>
     <item>
      <property name="text">
       <string>XY</string>
      </property>
     </item>
    </item>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>XY</string>
     </property>
     <item>
      <property name="text">
       <string>XY</string>
      </property>
     </item>
     <item>
      <property name="text">
       <string>XY</string>
      </property>
     </item>
     <item>
      <property name="text">
       <string>XY</string>
      </property>
     </item>
    </item>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>XY</string>
     </property>
     <item>
      <property name="text">
       <string>XY</string>
      </property>
     </item>
     <item>
      <property name="text">
       <string>XY</string>
      </property>
     </item>
     <item>
      <property name="text">
       <string>XY</string>
      </property>
     </item>
     <item>
      <property name="text">
       <string>XY</string>
      </property>
     </item>
    </item>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>XY</string>
     </property>
     <item>
      <property name="text">
       <string>XY</string>
      </property>
     </item>
    </item>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>XY</string>
     </property>
     <item>
      <property name="text">
       <string>XY</string>
      </property>
     </item>
    </item>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>XY</string>
     </property>
     <item>
      <property name="text">
       <string>XY</string>
      </property>
     </item>
    </item>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>XY</string>
     </property>
     <item>
      <property name="text">
       <string>XY</string>
      </property>
     </item>
     <item>
      <property name="text">
       <string>XY</string>
      </property>
     </item>
    </item>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>XY</string>
     </property>
     <item>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Weitere Links</string>
      </property>
     </item>
    </item>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuFile">
    <property name="title">
     <string>File</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="actionExit"/>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuEdit">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Settings</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuHelp">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Help</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="actionInfo"/>
   </widget>
   <addaction name="menuFile"/>
   <addaction name="menuEdit"/>
   <addaction name="menuHelp"/>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
  <action name="actionExit">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Exit</string>
   </property>
   <property name="statusTip">
    <string>Close the Application</string>
   </property>
   <property name="shortcut">
    <string>Esc</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionCopy">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Copy</string>
   </property>
   <property name="statusTip">
    <string>Copy a file</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionPase">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Pase</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionSave">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Save</string>
   </property>
   <property name="statusTip">
    <string>Save a file</string>
   </property>
   <property name="shortcut">
    <string>Ctrl+S</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionInfo">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Info</string>
   </property>
  </action>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

The main.py file

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QDialog, QTreeWidgetItem, QLabel
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi 
import sys 


class MainUI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainUI, self).__init__() 
        loadUi("dwhtool.ui", self)

        #Define Our Widgets 
        self.treeWidget.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.OpenLink)


    def OpenLink(self,item):
        if item.column() == 1:
            webbrowser.open('www.google.com')



    def exitApp(self):
        close()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = MainUI()
    ui.show() 
    app.exec()
```

Comment: You've posted the same file twice. Besides, it's unclear what you mean by "lowest tree level". Also, what is `webbrowser`?

Comment: Hello @musicamante I just corrected the .ui code. With lowest tree level is meant the "node" or leave. If you run the first code you will have a tree view. And the nodes can open child nodes. The child nodes should open the link

Comment: Tree widget items don't have columns, it's provided by the second argument of the [`itemDoubleClicked`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html#itemDoubleClicked) signal (which you omitted). Change to `def OpenLink(self, item, column):`. If you want to know if the item is not a parent, then just use [`item.childCount()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidgetitem.html#childCount): if it's 0, it means that it has no children.

Comment: @musicamante so how can I access the XY to open up in a URL?